# Typescript: Method to implement an interface with 3 different signatures?

Tags: node.js, typescript, winston

I am trying to wrap a function/method available in winston (node loggin framework), I have found its interface

```
interface LeveledLogMethod {
    (msg: string, callback: LogCallback): LoggerInstance;
    (msg: string, meta: any, callback: LogCallback): LoggerInstance;
    (msg: string, ...meta: any[]): LoggerInstance;
}
```

I would like to implement a method called "error" that would take the above signatures.

I am only wrapping it, so I will be calling the winston function directly.

If anybody is familiar with winston, I basically have 2 loggers setup and all consumers go through my main loggging class and I use either the 1st logger or second logger depending on the loglevel so I need to wrap it.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want to have an `error` function where? Is it a global one or a class method, if the latter then for which class exactly? Please provide more info/code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 3 interfaces this way:

```
interface A {}
interface B {}
interface C {}

const variable: A|B|C = {};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use optional properties and types to add that to your function so it matches the interface.

For example:

```js
interface LeveledLogMethod {
    (msg: string, callback: () => void): string;
    (msg: string, meta: any, callback: () => void): string;
    (msg: string, ...meta: any[]): string;
}

let error: LeveledLogMethod = function (msg: string, b: () => void | any, c?: () => void): string {
    return '';
}
```